# Why can't I call include from a class method in ruby?

Tags: ruby

You can call include to mixin a module with a class in ruby, but it must be done at the beginning of the class definition. Why can't it be done inside a class function? Is there an alternate syntax?

EX:

```
module UsefulThings
  def a() puts "a" end
end

class IncludeTester
  include UsefulThings
    def initialize
  end
end

n = IncludeTester.new
n.a()
```

^^ This works, but if I change IncludeTester to the following, I get the error "undefined method `include'"

```
class IncludeTester
  def initialize
    include UsefulThings
  end
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It *can* be done in a class method.

This works:

```
module UsefulThings
  def a
    puts "a" 
  end
end

class IncludeTester
  def self.mix_in_useful_things
    include UsefulThings
  end 
end

x = IncludeTester.new

IncludeTester.mix_in_useful_things

x.a # => a
```

But "initialize" is not a class method, it's an instance method.

"new" is a class method.  You can think of new as allocating a new object and then calling initialize on it, passing initialize whatever arguments were passed to new.

You can't call include directly in initialize because include is a private method of Class (inherited from Module), not of the newly created IncludeTester instance.

If you want to include a module into a class from an instance method, you have to do something like this:

```
class IncludeTester
  def initialize
    self.class.send(:include, UsefulThings)
  end
end
```

It's necessary to use "send" here because include is private method, which means it can only be directly invoked with an implicit receiver (of self).

When you call initialize normally in a class definition, you're actually calling it with an implicit receiver of "self", referring to the class being defined.

This is what is actually happening when you do this:

```
class IncludeTester
  include UsefulThings
end
```

Comment: Yes, this is incredibly helpful (as were the other answers).

Answer (score 4):

[`include`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.html#M000440) is a method from Module, Module is the superclass of Class and so `include` is a method on Class and that makes it a class method in your IncludeTester. When you do this:

```
class IncludeTester
  def initialize
    include UsefulThings
  end
end
```

you're trying to call a class method inside an instance method and Ruby says

> `initialize': undefined method `include'

because there is no instance method called `include`. If you want to call a class method inside an instance method (such as `initialize`), you'd do this:

```
def initialize
  self.class.include UsefulThings
end
```

But that won't work because `include` is a private method; you can get around that with [`class_eval`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.html#M000437) though:

```
def initialize
  self.class.class_eval {
    include UsefulThings
  }
end
```

You would be doing `include UsefulThings` every single time you instantiated an `IncludeTester`, aside from not making much sense, it could cause problems if `UsefulThings` had an [`included`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.html#M000458) method.

Comment: The idiomatic way of circumventing access protection for private methods is to use `send`, not any of the `eval` methods.

Answer (score 2):

It's actually fully possible to include a module from a class method, like so:

```
module Stuff
  def say_hello
    puts "hello"
  end
end

class Foo
  def self.i_am_a_class_method
    include Stuff
  end

  def i_am_an_instance_method
  end
end
```

You cannot however do that from an instance method, because the [include method](http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/include) is only available as a private class method, and therefore not accessible from a Foo.new instance.

Answer (score 0):

You want the `extend` method:

```
class IncludeTester
  def initialize
    extend UsefulThings
  end
end
```

This need not be done within the a method either:

```
IncludeTester.new.tap { |newTester| newTester.extend(UsefulThings) }
```

Comment: Almost! Calling "extend" from an instance method doesn't mix the module into the instance's class -- it causes an invisible "ghost" class to be added to the beginning of the object's inheritance chain (ahead of the actual class) and mixes the module into that.  Mixing a module in like this doesn't affect other objects of the same class.